# Excel VBA listing all unique values from a column, and all corresponding values to each unique value from another column

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I am a novice with VBA/Macros and do not know the technical terms or the best ways to perform many functions. However, I was able to create a Macro that partially does what I need it to, but I can't seem to figure out the rest.

The Situation: I have vulnerability scan results that I'm attempting to parse a certain way so that I can get relevant information out properly so that I can provide it in a clean and concise way to my teams. Currently I get the vuln results into an excel file which has all of the information per vuln, per host (so 1 vuln showing on 6 hosts, produces 6 rows). My current Macro is able to distill the information down so that I can view it as 1 row per vuln (indicated by a unique PluginID), with all of the hosts concatenated into 1 cell delimited by a line break. The current macro accomplishes this well, however there is another column within the vuln results that is very important - "Vulnerability Proof". On some vulns, the "Vulnerability Proof" is the same for all hosts with the vuln, and on some its different.
I need to be able to list all unique "vulnerability proofs" with all of the hosts that the proof is related to, so that I get a concise list of "these hosts have this proof, these hosts have this proof etc."

Here some sample source data:

| PluginID | Description | Host | Vuln Proof |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Plugin123 | CVE-Plugin123 | Host1 | Version 1.2.3 detected |
| Plugin123 | CVE-Plugin123 | Host2 | Version 1.2.3 detected |
| Plugin123 | CVE-Plugin123 | Host3 | Version 4.5.6 detected |
| Plugin456 | Plugin456-2021 Vuln | Host1 | Version 7.8.9 detected |
| Plugin456 | Plugin456-2021 Vuln | Host2 | Version 10.11.12 detected |
| Plugin456 | Plugin456-2021 Vuln | Host3 | Version 10.11.12 detected |

Currently when I run my macro (below), I get the following output:

| PluginID | Description | Host | Vuln Proof |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Plugin123 | CVE-Plugin123 | Host1, Host2, Host3 | Version 1.2.3 detected, Version 1.2.3 detected, Version 4.5.6 detected |
| Plugin456 | Plugin456-2021 Vuln | Host1, Host2, Host3 | Version 7.8.9 detected, Version 10.11.12 detected, Version 10.11.12 detected |

This, while achieving the goal of reviewing by 1 row per vuln, doesn't give a very good way to review the vulnerability proof if/when that proof is long, and/or there are many, many hosts reporting the vuln.

How I'd like to receive the output:

| PluginID | Description | Host | Vuln Proof |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Plugin123 | CVE-Plugin123 | Host1, Host2, Host3 | Host1, Host 2: Version 1.2.3 detected Host 3: Version 4.5.6 detected |
| Plugin456 | Plugin456-2021 Vuln | Host1, Host2, Host3 | Host 1: Version 7.8.9 detected Host 2, Host3: Version 10.11.12 detected |

My current Macro looks like this:

```
Sub CombineDupRows()
    Dim cCR As cCombinedRows
    Dim colCR As Collection
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, wsRes As Worksheet, rRes As Range
    Dim vSrc As Variant, vRes() As Variant
    Dim S As String
    Dim I As Long, J As Long
    
Sheets("Results").Activate
    
Set wsSrc = Worksheets("Source")
Set wsRes = Worksheets("Results")
    Set rRes = wsRes.Cells(1, 1)
    
With wsSrc
    vSrc = .Range("a1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Resize(columnsize:=4)
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'collect source data
Set colCR = New Collection
On Error Resume Next
For I = 1 To UBound(vSrc)
    Set cCR = New cCombinedRows
    With cCR
        For J = 1 To 2
            .Key(J) = CStr(vSrc(I, J))
        Next J
        
        .Phrase(0) = vSrc(I, 3)
        .ProofPhrase(0) = vSrc(I, 4)
        
        'The key will be the concatenation of columns 1-2
        S = Join(.Keys, Chr(1))
        
        'if key is duplicate, add phrase to existing collection item
        On Error Resume Next
            colCR.Add cCR, S
            Select Case Err.Number
                Case 457  'duplicate key
                    Err.Clear
                    colCR(S).Phrase(UBound(colCR(S).Phrases) + 1) = .Phrase(0)
                    colCR(S).ProofPhrase(UBound(colCR(S).ProofPhrases) + 1) = .ProofPhrase(0)
                Case Is <> 0  'some other error.  Stop for debugging
                    Debug.Print Err.Number, Err.Description, Err.Source
                    Stop
                End Select
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With
Next I

'Create results array
ReDim vRes(1 To colCR.Count, 1 To 4)
For I = 1 To colCR.Count
    With colCR(I)
        For J = 1 To 2
            vRes(I, J) = colCR(I).Key(J)
        Next J
        vRes(I, J) = Join(.Phrases, " " & Chr(13) & Chr(10))
        vRes(I, 4) = Join(.ProofPhrases, " " & Chr(13) & Chr(10))
    End With
Next I

Set rRes = rRes.Resize(UBound(vRes, 1), UBound(vRes, 2))
With rRes
    .Value = vRes
End With
```

As part of this, I also had to create a Class Module which looks like this:

```
Option Explicit
Private pKeys() As String
Private pKey As String
Private pPhrases() As String
Private pPhrase As String
Private ProofpPhrases() As String
Private ProofpPhrase As String

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    ReDim pKeys(0)
    ReDim pPhrases(0)
    ReDim ProofpPhrases(0)
End Sub


Public Property Get Keys() As String()
    Keys = pKeys
End Property

Public Property Get Key(index As Long) As String
    Key = pKeys(index)
End Property

Public Property Let Key(index As Long, strValue As String)
    If index > UBound(pKeys) Then ReDim Preserve pKeys(index)
    pKeys(index) = strValue
End Property

Public Property Get Phrases() As String()
    Phrases = pPhrases
End Property

Public Property Get Phrase(index As Long) As String
    Phrase = pPhrases(index)
End Property

Public Property Let Phrase(index As Long, strValue As String)
    If index > UBound(pPhrases) Then ReDim Preserve pPhrases(index)
    pPhrases(index) = strValue
End Property

Public Property Get ProofPhrases() As String()
    ProofPhrases = ProofpPhrases
End Property

Public Property Get ProofPhrase(index As Long) As String
    ProofPhrase = ProofpPhrases(index)
End Property

Public Property Let ProofPhrase(index As Long, strValue As String)
    If index > UBound(ProofpPhrases) Then ReDim Preserve ProofpPhrases(index)
    ProofpPhrases(index) = strValue
End Property
```

I've attempted to add some string types for the host again which could be used to provide some sort of concatenating in the proof column in the results, but I haven't been successful thus far even with that (even though its not even fully what I am looking for).
I've spent a good amount of time tinkering and attempting to get this to work, and am finally asking for help. What can I add to the Macro to get this to work to get results out the way I'm looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been trying to learn Power Query (available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Office 365), so I will present this six-step procedure as an alternative.

To use Power Query

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

**M Code**

```
let

//Change Name in next line to actual name in your workbook
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table22"]}[Content],

//Set data types
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"PluginID", type text}, 
        {"Description", type text}, 
        {"Host", type text}, 
        {"Vuln Proof", type text}}),

//Group by PluginID
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"PluginID"}, {

//If there is more than on associated Description, not sure what you want to do
//  so we only return the first entry
        {"Description", each [Description]{0}},

// Aggregate the Hosts
        {"Host", each Text.Combine([Host], ", ")},

// Combine Host:Vuln Proofs by grouping each subgroup by the Vuln Proof
// and extracting the associated Hosts
        {"Vuln Proof", (t)=> Table.Group(t, "Vuln Proof",{
            {"Hosts", (x)=> Text.Combine(x[Host],", ")}})}}),

// Add custom column to create a list of the vuln proof and hosts from each subtable
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Custom", 
        each List.Transform(List.Zip({[Vuln Proof][Hosts],[Vuln Proof][Vuln Proof]}),
                                each Text.Combine(_,":"))),

//Then concatenate the list of hostes with the vuln proof
    #"Extracted Values" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Custom", 
        {"Custom", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), "#(lf)"), type text}),

//remove unneeded column        
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Extracted Values",{"Vuln Proof"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful. The vuln results actually have about 12 fields that I match against (primarily the plugin ID), so that if those first 12 fields are the same then they are combined into 1 (they should always be the same if the plugin ID matches anyways). If I wanted to group on 12 how would I do it? I've started playing with this and I get an error that said ''' Expression.Error: 14 arguments were passed to a function which expects between 3 and 5. '''

Comment: @Cbohn Not sure what you mean. If the 12 different *vuln results* are all in the same column, you shouldn't need to change anything.

Comment: Thanks, I actually meant there are 12 different columns that should act as the "key" (I think thats the right terminology for that table.group function. I figured out that if I just add the columns that also need to act as the "Key" to where you had "PluginID" separated with commas then it worked.

So essentially I replaced:
 #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"PluginID"}, {

With
 #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"PluginID","Description" etc. etc}, {

And it worked! 
I appreciate the help!

Comment: @Cbohn Glad you were able to adapt it to your data.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd tackle it - sorry did not have time to try to understand/adapt your code...

```vb
Sub Combine()
    Const SEP As String = "~~~"
    Dim r As Long, dictHosts As Object, dictProofs As Object, kp, k, host, proof
    Dim data, dict As Object, c As Range, s As String
    
    Set dictHosts = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set dictProofs = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

    'read all data to array for processing
    data = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:D" & ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Value
    
    'process and combine
    For r = 1 To UBound(data, 1)
        k = data(r, 1) & SEP & data(r, 2)
        host = data(r, 3)
        proof = data(r, 4)
        'tracking vuln vs hosts
        If Not dictHosts.exists(k) Then dictHosts.Add k, New Collection 'new vuln
        dictHosts(k).Add host                              'add host for this vuln
        
        'tracking vuln vs host<>proof
        If Not dictProofs.exists(k) Then dictProofs.Add k, CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
        Set dict = dictProofs(k)
        If Not dict.exists(proof) Then dict.Add proof, New Collection
        dict(proof).Add host
    Next r
    
    'output results
    Set c = ActiveSheet.Range("G1")
    For Each k In dictHosts
        c.Value = Split(k, SEP)(0)               'plugin ID
        c.Offset(0, 1).Value = Split(k, SEP)(1)  'description
        c.Offset(0, 2).Value = Join(ColToArray(dictHosts(k)), ", ") 'list of hosts
        s = ""
        Set dict = dictProofs(k)
        'build the proof: hosts string
        For Each kp In dict
            s = s & IIf(s <> "", vbLf, "") & kp & ": " & Join(ColToArray(dict(kp)), ",")
        Next kp
        c.Offset(0, 3).Value = s
        
        Set c = c.Offset(1, 0)
    Next k
End Sub

'Utility function: get an array from a Collection
Function ColToArray(col As Collection)
    Dim v, arr, i
    ReDim arr(0 To col.Count - 1)
    For i = 1 To col.Count
        arr(i - 1) = col(i)
    Next i
    ColToArray = arr
End Function
```